# Angular 6 reload same page when you refresh with browser

Tags: javascript, angular

**The problem**

If the URL in my browser is /portfolio and I'm showing the PortfolioComponent, I'd like to reload that page and component when the user hits refresh in their browser.

What actually happens is that the page reloads to index "/" and shows the associated component.

**What I would like to happen**

If I'm on /portfolio, if I hit refresh or press F5 I'd like to stay on /portfolio and for the associated component to reload.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: It is weird. It should stay same. Which server do you use? If you are using `apache`, it may be about `.htaccess`.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken it's a default behavior of Angular's router to do that. You might need to change the server settings to let the angular do the routing instead of server (redirect everything to index.html without changing request_uri).

Comment: you need to leverage sessionStorage to remember the last visited path, so a refresh will redirect to that url

Comment: Is this occurring when serving locally with Node? Locally with another HTTP Server? Or is it deployed and being served from a remote server? If so which HTTP Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. easy way is to use

> hash location strategy

2. a little more hard way is to configure your web server to do the redirect for default

> path location strategy